# OnlyOffice - Access local files from a website

Tags: php, docker, localhost, onlyoffice

I want to be able to **open the Office documents that are present on my PC from my website** (in the long term they will be files stored on the NAS server of our network)

So I installed **[OnlyOffice](https://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/installation/docs-community-install-docker.aspx?_ga=2.203680272.1285654786.1609847282-994283078.1606924353)** thanks to docker on my PC via this command (I'm on Windows 10)

```
docker run -i -t -d -p 90:80 --restart=always onlyoffice/documentserver
```

I used port 90 because port 80 is already used by Wamp

Then on my website hosted locally thanks to Wamp I created this file :

**Index.html**

```
<div id="placeholder" style="height: 100%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:90/web-apps/apps/api/documents/api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.docEditor = new DocsAPI.DocEditor("placeholder",
  {
    "document": {
      "fileType": "docx",
      "title": "Example Document Title.docx",
      "url": "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/file-sample_500kB.docx"

    },
    "documentType": "word",
    "editorConfig": {
      "mode": "view"
    },
    "height": "100%",
    "width": "100%"
  });
</script>
```

(Using the url of an external site it works)

So I modified my script to retrieve a locally hosted file in this way

NB: `http://mysite.test` is a vhost corresponding to `http://localhost/mysite` (on WAMP)

**Index.html (version 2)**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:90/web-apps/apps/api/documents/api.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.docEditor = new DocsAPI.DocEditor("placeholder",
  {
    "document": {
      "fileType": "docx",
      "title": "Example Document Title.docx",
      "url": "http://mysite.test/get_file.php"

    },
    "documentType": "word",
    "editorConfig": {
      "mode": "view"
    },
    "height": "100%",
    "width": "100%"
  });
</script>
```

**get_file.php**

```
<?php
$file_url = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.docx';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.docx"); 
readfile($file_url); 
?>
```

**And there it does not work!** (the file is correctly downloaded if I access directly from the link `http://mysite.test/get_file.php`)

I have this error on index.html :

```
Download failed.
```

**Docker Logs :**

```
[2021-01-06T14:04:18.136] [ERROR] nodeJS - error downloadFile:url=http://mysite.test/get_file.php;attempt=3;code:null;connect:null;(id=127d6893c0ab2f9f8b71)
Error: Error response: statusCode:404 ;body:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /get_file.php</pre>
</body>
</html>
at Request._callback (/snapshot/server/build/server/Common/sources/utils.js:0:0)
at Request.init.self.callback (/snapshot/server/build/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (/snapshot/server/build/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/snapshot/server/build/server/Common/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
at Gunzip.emit (events.js:203:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I use a get_file.php PHP file because in the end it will be the one who will manage the rights of the users already present on the site (example user1 can only access .docx files and user2 only files .xlsx)

**Can you tell me how to view my local files (futurement on a NAS server) using OnlyOffice?**

Comment: "does not work" means what precisely? That's not a fixable error. Try to give specific technical information - e.g. error messages in the Console or Network tools, and/or specifics about how the program behaves.

Comment: @ADyson I'm sorry, I forgot to put the error message, I edited my post (thank you)

Comment: From the log it looks like something has somehow translated the URL into `http://mysite.test/get_file/` instead of `http://mysite.test/get_file.php`. It's not obvious how that's happened though, from what you've shown. Also it says `nodeJS`...where does nodeJS come into this? You've shown client-side JS, and PHP, so far.

Comment: @ADyson The error on the link is fixed, it came from my htaccess, I modified my post
but I have no idea where nodejs is from, I think it is from OnlyOffice